# url Routing for a WebMethod in webforms

Tags: routes, webforms

I have a web service contains a web method with the url http://localhost/Service1.asmx?op=AddNumbers . which my client wants to call it in something like http://localhost:55228/Service1.asmx/AddNumbers. any suggestions for routing a webmethod URL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it through the URL Rewriting over the IIS layer.